# What are good textbooks or documents to learn numerical simulation about open channel flow like river flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, flow

I'm trying to learn about numerical simulation about river flow.

The problem is I am a CFD beginner (just studied about hydraulics).

So I don't know history or important topics about numerical simulation about open channel flow.

I want to know good books or other documents like review papers.

Comment: Interesting question... I can give tons of references for general CFD/numerical methods that include a range of equations and types of models. But none of them have the shallow water equations, sediment transport models, etc... I'll see if I can find something that has river flow as the "punchline" instead of the full-on Navier-Stokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this is a mediocre answer because I don't own the book nor have I read it, so I cannot assess it clearly. I am pretty curious about it so I may try to pick up a copy. However, doing a really quick literature search, the book [Computational River Dynamics](https://www.crcpress.com/Computational-River-Dynamics/Wu/p/book/9780415449601) by CRC Press seems like it has all the ingredients to be a good introduction based on the description and table of contents. It also appears to be fairly well cited.

It covers the governing equations and submodels that are needed -- sediment transport, simplified 1D/2D models as well as the full 3D models, etc.. It also covers numerical methods and a variety of formulations that can be used.

It seems targeted as a reference book, but says it has worked examples. So it may be less narrative and more formulaic, but I cannot determine that without the book. However, it will almost certainly have references in it that point to good review articles and papers with details on all of the methods it covers.

Comment: Been a while since I've looked at it, but do Leveque's or Toro's books cover open channels at all?

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't have either handy at the moment... I don't recall either of them discussing it, but I could be mistaken. I know the Sod shock tube is also called the dam breaking problem in the hydrology community using the shallow water equations, either book may have made that connection. But I'd have to wait until Tuesday to get my hands on the books again.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply and thank you for your helpful opinions. I'll check the content of of the CRC book. And Leveque's and Toro's books are [this](https://www.amazon.co.jp/Computational-Methods-Astrophysical-Saas-Fee-Advanced/dp/3540644482) and [this](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540252023) ?

Comment: @F.Yudai You have the correct Toro book. To me, the "Leveque book" usually refers to [*Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems*](https://www.amazon.com/Methods-Hyperbolic-Problems-Cambridge-Mathematics/dp/0521009243). Of course, Leveque has [several books](https://staff.washington.edu/rjl/booksnotes.html) so it is hard to know which one anybody means...

Comment: @KyleKanos Can you weigh in for which Leveque book you meant? I can also recommend [*Computational Fluid Mechanics and Heat Transfer*](https://www.amazon.com/Computational-Mechanics-Transfer-Physical-Processes/dp/1591690374) for general CFD/numerical methods. It's a big book, it covers almost everything, but I think it is Navier-Stokes focused. It's with the rest of my books at work and I haven't been in yet to look at it for channel flow.

Comment: LeVeque's [*Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems*](https://www.amazon.com/Methods-Hyperbolic-Problems-Cambridge-Mathematics/dp/0521009243)